# Postgresql - efficient select distinct

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, distinct

I have a query that is taking too much time to run and I am trying to simplify it. I used https://explain.depesz.com/, and apparently my "unique" node is consuming a lot of computation time.

I am calculating the maximum over a partition, and then using `distinct on` to keep the maximal value and the other column.

Here is an example:

| class | student | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 1 | B | 10 |
| 1 | C | 11 |
| 1 | D | 7 |
| 2 | E | 20 |
| 2 | F | 18 |
| 2 | G | 19 |

Basically I want the maximal grade per classroom:

| class | max_grade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 20 |

what I currently do is:

```
select distinct on (class)
       class, max_grade 
from (select max(grade) over (partition by class) as max_grade,
             student,
             class)
```

Is there a better way to obtain this result than using `distinct on`?

Comment: Better than what?  You didn't show anything, neither the query nor it's plan.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question or ask another.

Comment: I just added the query

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest of aggregate queries.

```
SELECT class, MAX(grade) FROM tbl GROUP BY class
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives the right result but it is slower than my distinct query

Comment: You're right. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @cobdmg that is hard to believe as a reproducible result of any meaningfully-sized data set.